# How to create a api which return array of string?

Tags: spring-boot

["Non Dox", "Dox"] --> create  a method for this and how i call in controller method also
i want this from api how i will be able to do it in spring boot

```
public static String[] demo()
{
    String[] xs = new String[] {"Dox","NonDox"};
    return xs;
} //method for array of string
```

```
@GetMapping("/url") public String[] getArray(){ return employeeService.demo(); } //call in controller
```

Comment: Hope you are using @RestController annotation. you can use ResponseEntity<List<your Array name>> and get result from your demo method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to stick with `String[]` arrays, but you can create a `List<String>` instead and have a Controller return this. I've set up such a Controller for you (I was doing some research on Spring Boot and primitives/arrays but I couldn't find any documentation on best practices for this).

Your `static List` would look like this:

```
    static List<String> list() {
        return new ArrayList<>() {
            {
                add("Dox");
                add("NonDox");
            }};
    }

    @GetMapping("/url")
    public List<String> getList(){
        return list();
    }
```